# What Big-O notation would this fall under?

Tags: big-o

What Big-O notation would this fall under? I know setSearch() and removeAt() are of order O(n) (assume they are either way). I know without the for loop it'd be O(n), for certain, but I get confused how to calculate what it becomes with a for loop thrown into it. I'm not all that great at math... so. Would it be O(n^2)?

```
public void removeAll(DataElement clearElement)
{
     if(length == 0)
         System.err.println("Cannot delete from an empty list.");
     else
     {
         for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
         {      
            loc = seqSearch(clearElement);

            if(loc != -1)
            {      
               removeAt(loc);
                --i;
             }
         } 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Depends on how much seqSearch and removeAt cost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If removeAt() and seqSearch() are O(n) with respect to the length of the list then yes, this algorithm would be of order O(n^2). This is because within the for loop you call seqSearch every time, with a possibility of calling removeAt(loc). That means for each iteration you are doing either n or 2n operations. Taking the worst case, you have 2n^2 operations which is O(n^2).

Comment: Hmm, making more sense, what if say, removeAt() were of order O(1), would that then turn it into a order of O(n)? or would that still be O(n^2)?

Comment: @diskotech yes it would still be O(n^2) because the worst case is still running seqSearch n times per iteration. Algorithms with 2n^2 and 100n^2 worst case complexities are all O(n^2).